# Create Nuxt.js list with async data & axios

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I try to load data from Json to vue component using this tutorial:
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/

This is my code:

```
<li class="item" v-for="post in posts"  v-bind:key="post.id">
  <nuxt-link :to="....">
   {{post.id}}. {{post.title}}
  </nuxt-link>
</li>

import axios from "axios";
export default {
    async data () {
      let { data } = await axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder/`)
      return { posts: data } // Console: property post is not defined
    }
  }
```

Tell me please, what's wrong?

Comment: It should be `async asyncData` instead of `async data`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this based on Nuxt [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/api/) and the [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) guide, i.e.:

```
export default {
  async asyncData(context) {
    let response = await context.app.$axios.$get(`http://jsonplaceholder/`)
    return { posts: response } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explaining more sid heart's reply:
Function name is "asyncData" not async data. You are using async await you can use like this:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  // Also define data function and define posts property
  data() {
    return {
      posts: {}
    }
  },

  async asyncData () {
    let { data } = await axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder/`)
    return { posts: data } // Console: property post is not defined
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Nuxt.Js](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#async-data) documentation, `async asyncData` should be written instead of `async data` and there is no need to import axios and you should get it from the `asyncData` input parameters.

```
<li class="item" v-for="post in posts"  v-bind:key="post.id">
  <nuxt-link :to="....">
   {{post.id}}. {{post.title}}
  </nuxt-link>
</li>

export default {
  async asyncData ({ $axios }) {
    const data = await $axios.$get('http://jsonplaceholder/')
    return { posts: data } // Console: property post is not defined
  },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

according to nuxtjs document

```
  async asyncData ({ params }) {
    let { data } = await axios.get(`https://my-api/posts/${params.id}`)
    return { title: data.title }
  }
```

in your case this should be

```
async asyncData () {
    let { data } = await axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder/`)
    return { posts: data } // Console: property post is not defined
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use like below ( as per [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/api/) and [Context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) docs.)

```
export default {
   async asyncData({params, app}) {
    const { data } = await app.$axios.get(`https://www.yoursite.com/user/${params.id}/`)
    return { posts: data } 
  }
}
```